# Ubuntu 16.04 and Chrome managment

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, administration

First of all, I'd like to greet everyone, it's my first post on this forum.

I got two questions about Chrome browser in Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus).

I need to find out how to manage it from Terminal - I mean making permanent changes in settings (e.g. how to set homepage permanently, I know I can start it by addding "http://www.example.com" ,but it doesn't solve my problems.)

Second question concerns about managing Chrome extensions via terminal - or - if it's not possible - I need know place where configuration of certain extension is stored on disk.

Best regards.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do either of the things you want from the terminal. Use the browser itself.

Comment: I know it's possible with Firefox someway. In case of changing browser on production I'm taking care of I need to know it.